# Eclipse plugin-in development - New Project Wizard

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Iam very new to Eclipse plugin development and seriously struck in the first step only.I have a requirement to create a custom plugin in eclipse, where i have to create a New Project Wizard on click of New -->Project.
All the basic setting like Wizard creation and category is done and on click of Project iam getting the Project creation screen also. Now from here when i click on the Next Button i need to popup configuration popup.

- Step -1

  The first screen to come when i click on the New Project is Create project wizard, which i'am able to achieve by using a WizardNewProjectCreationPage in my WizardPageCreation class and using it in addPage() method.
- Step 2

I want the second page to be a configuration page [when i click Next button from the First Wizard Page ] with debug and release check boxes. How to achieve this ?

Comment: `WizardPage` is the normal page to extend. But it isn't really clear what you are asking here.

Comment: i need to create a screen as shown in the link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cdd3b3lluu4uu4y/config.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

As you have already done adding first page using addPage(). You should add your second page in the same fashion. Wizard can contain multiple pages. You need to add each of them using addPage() method. And in your second page you can provide whatever implementation you need.

You need to provide implementation for on click of next method which shall load the second page.

Comment: yes i appretiate that i can add the second page in the addPage() method. But my problem is how to achieve a configuration screen. Which class i should extend or what type i should use